# Logged out sidebar weirdness

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, logout, login-control

When I'm logged in to my site, viewing an individual post, the right sidebar displays perfectly, but when I log out on the same page (via the sidebar widget), the right sidebar suddenly ends up below my comments.  This only happens with I'm viewing individual posts.  Any ideas what causing this?

I've double checked the CSS, and as far as I can tell being logged out doesn't add or change any class attributes.  Also - the theme I'm working with doesn't have a posts.php file...

Post: http://www.wespeakfashion.com/cool-sunglasses

page.php...

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/header.php'); ?>

<div id="content">

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/l_sidebar.php");?>

<div id="contentleft">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(__('Read more'));?><div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <!--
    <?php trackback_rdf(); ?>
    -->

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php endif; ?>
    <?php posts_nav_link(' &#8212; ', __('&laquo; go back'), __('keep looking &raquo;')); ?>

    </div>

<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/r_sidebar.php");?>

</div>

<!-- The main column ends  -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right sidebar appears to be in the main content div. This is suspicious because the left sidebar is a sibling of the main content div. Try taking the right sidebar out of there, and putting it as a sibling of the left sidebar and main content div.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the page.php.  As you can see, the right sidebar is a sibling of the left sidebar and contentleft.

Comment: Not according to Chrome. On Chrome, I can see that `rsidebar` is a child of `contentleft`. `lsidebar` is a sibling of `contentleft`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not what I see.  I just viewed the source, and rsidebar is a sibling of contentleft and lsidebar, and they're the children of content.  Please point out where I'm wrong, if that's the case.

Comment: Good gravy.  So why is that happening?  It seems that when I'm viewing individual posts, and only when I'm viewing individual posts, that it kicks rsidebar into content left...?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have little experience with Wordpress :\. Not really sure why that is happening.

Comment: I think I just figured it out.  I was using a bit of PHP to add a div when users are logged out, and it was breaking the html.  I'll give you the credit for putting up with me ;)  Thanks!